# Difference between "gets(s);" and "scanf("%s", s);" in C

Tags: c, string, scanf, gets

I am writing a program that allows users to enter five names and sorts the names in Alphabet order, two adjacent names seperated by a newline character. Here is my code:

```
void sortWords(char s[][100], int n){
    int i, j;
    char *str;
    for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        for(j = n- 1; j > i; j--){
            if(strcmp(s[j], s[j-1]) == -1){
                strcpy(str, s[j]);
                strcpy(s[j], s[j-1]);
                strcpy(s[j-1], str);
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    char s[5][100];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        fflush(stdin);
        //gets(s[i]);      // when I use this statement, my program doesn't work
        scanf("%s", s[i]);
    }
    sortWords(s, 5);
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%s ", s[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I changed the "scanf" in function main to "gets", after I have entered 5 names, the program just didn't print anything. Can anyone explain it for me, because normally, when I change one of them to the other function, I just have same results.

Comment: Firstly and very importantly: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used). Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `gets`?

Comment: Second (also very important): [Using fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209/10871073)

Comment: Please describe the problem better than "doesn't work". `scanf("%s")` only reads a single word (ie, stops at first white space). `fgets` reads a whole line (including spaces and multiple words).

Comment: cppreference also mentions to use [gets_s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) instead of `gets`.

Comment: The you have formatted `scanf()`, they are both equally dangerous.

Comment: @Damien The C standard itself recommends `fgets` over `gets_s`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> allows users to enter five names

Names usually have a space between the parts of the full name.  `scanf("%s", s)` does not read a full name, but only part of a name.

Code has many other problems too.

---

> Difference between "gets(s);" and "scanf("%s", s);" in C

One reads a *line* the other reads a *word*.

- `gets()`, since C11 (2011) is no longer part of the C standard library.
- Both are bad as they do not limit input and so can suffer buffer overflow.
- The obsolete `gets()` would read and save a *line* - input unto and including the `'\n'`.  The `'\n'` is read, but not saved.  If the prior input operation left a `'\n'` in `stdin`, then `gets()` reads a short line of `"\n"` and saves as `""`.
- `scanf("%s", s)` reads and discards any number of leading white-space characters (perhaps multiple `'\n'`) and then reads and saves non-white-spaces.  A following white-space stops the reading, but it is returned to `stdin` for the next input function.
- With common input, `scanf("%s", s)` typically the leaves the final `'\n'` in `stdin` for the next input operation.  `gets()` consumes it.
- Both append a *null character* to `s` if any reading occurred.
- `gets()` returns a pointer.  `scanf()` returns a conversion count.

Recommendations

- Do not use either `gets(s)` nor `scanf("%s", s)` in production code.  To read a *line*, research `fgets()`.  To read a word, research using a *width* like `char s[100]; scanf("%99s", s);`.
- Best to test the return value of I/O functions.
- Do not mix `fgets()/gets()` with `scanf()` functions until you understand why that is bad.

---

**Other**

- `if(strcmp(s[j], s[j-1]) == -1)` is poor.  `strcmp()` returns some negative, zero or some positive to indicate order.  Better to use `if(strcmp(s[j], s[j-1]) < 0)`.
- `strcpy(str, s[j]);` is bad as pointer `str` has not been assigned a value.  Better as `char str[100]; strcpy(str, s[j]);`.

Answer (score 1):

`gets()` reads a **line**, `scanf("%s")` reads a **word**, and both should not be used.

<sub>for details, read @chuxReinstateMonica's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71526335/1593077).</sub>